# Login CORS issue

Tags: cordova, cors, google-signin

am using google as login provider but when i set the access control to wildcard like this :

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

login via google stop working 
But it works properly when i use

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');
```

which is the `JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` and the `REDIRECT URIS` i specified in the google console.
but now i want to deploy my app up on phone device i need to set it to wild card `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`. since my app on phone not working on `localhost:8100 anymore` 
Other login provider like Facebook working fine in both set ups.
I also would like to ask how could i debug my app when its deployed on phone device. 
note its `cordova` base App.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust CROSS ORIGIN on your server side, not on your client side.

Comment: You need to change it from there. Not on client side.